# Отправка файла через AJAX, используя PHPMailer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Не отправляется прикрепляемый файл.
С форм данные приходят, но только не сам файл. Как передать `AJAX`-ом переменную `$_FILES` ???

HTML формы

```
<form action="" name="send-form" id="send-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-line">
        <input type="text" required name="email" placeholder="">
    </div>

    <div class="input-line">
        <input type="text" required name="search-name" placeholder="">
    </div>

    <div class="input-line">
        <input type="file" id="photo-file" name="photo" placeholder="">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#send-form').submit(function () {
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "mail.php",
    data: form_data,
    success: function() {
        }
    });    
    return false;   
});
```

PHP обработчик

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
    $mail->Username = '';                 
    $mail->Password = '';                         
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                          
    $mail->Port = 465;                                   

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);    

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["photo"]["name"]);    

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Заявка c сайта';
    $mail->Body    = '<html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Почта для связи: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                        <p>Имя для поиска: '.$_POST['search-name'].'</p>    
                    </body>
                </html>';
    $mail->AltBody = '';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Сообщение успешно отправлено';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Не удалось отправить сообщение ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#send-form').submit(function(e) {

    var $file = $('#photo-file'),
        $email = $('[name="email"]'),
        $search_name = $('[name="search-name"]'),
        frm = new FormData;

    frm.append('photo', $file.get(0).files);
    frm.append('email', $email);
    frm.append('search-name', $search_name);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: frm,
       success: function() {}
    });
})
```

Comment: frm.append('photo', $file.files[0]); - на этой строчке выдает Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: frm.append('photo', $file.prop('files')[0]) - пробовал так как в другом решении, тогда вообще ошибка Illegal invocation на строчке с $.ajax({

Comment: @Владимир да, я там ошибся, изменил ответ.

Comment: добавил processData: false,  contentType: false, - исчезла ошибка Illegal invocation , теперь не могу адрес почты задавать через $_POST[email] и прикрепляемого файла по прежнему нет.

Comment: И сообщения приходят в формате [object Object]

Comment: тогда добавьте contentType: 'json' и на сервере json_decode($_POST);

Comment: json_decode($_POST); в обработчик добавлять? Если да то куда?

Comment: перед началом обработки данных из ($_POST)